# TYPO3 - TCA Migrations Check shows 4th parameter 'specConf' of the field 'showitem' with fieldName = 'sys_language_uid' has been migrated

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

After upgrading from 7LTS to 8LTS and running TCA Migrations Check for my extensions the result list shows the following:

Comment:

> The 4th parameter 'specConf' of the field 'showitem' with fieldName = 'sys_language_uid' has been migrated, from TCA table "tx_myextension_domain_model_accounts['types']['1']['showitem']"to "tx_myextension_domain_model_accounts['types']['1']['columnsOverrides']['sys_language_uid']['defaultExtras']".

In TCA I think this is the spot:

```php
    'types' => array(
        '1' => array('showitem' => 'sys_language_uid;;;;1-1-1, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden;;1, --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime'),
    ),
```

What changes do I need to do to get rid of comment?

I think this is the relevant part: 
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.3/Deprecation-67229-TcaChanges.html

And this comment as well?:

> Migrated 'showitem' field from TCA table tx_accountmanager_domain_model_accounts['types']['1']" : Moved additional palette with name "tx_myextension_domain_model_accounts['types']['1']['1']" as 3rd argument of field "tx_myextension_domain_model_accounts['types']['1']['hidden']"to an own palette. The result of this part is: "hidden, --palette--;;1"

Comment: Have a look at BE modul 'Configuration' under 'TCA'. There you will find changes to your TCA configuration, which you can copy from there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ... I wasn't aware of that ...

Comment: If these changes are not applied right away, will the extension still work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may drop the whole `;;;;1-1-1` thing from your `sys_language_uid` field.

The best way to compare your original TCA with the migrated TCA is using the backend module "Configuration" and clicking through the TCA tree.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand: in Configuration > TCA: should I see the "migrated" TCA and copy the line from there (or some highlighted changes, which I don't see)

Comment: @urs You see the migrated version, no highlights, just copy from there to your TCA File.

Comment: @bandanh can you give an example? Paste at end of TCA file or adapt TCA structure according to changes?

Comment: Remove ;;;;1-1-1 at all fields

Answer (score 6):

Here a way to fix it, using the migrated version of the Backend Module `Configuration`:

If install tool > `TCA Migrations` says the following:

> The 4th parameter 'specConf' of the field 'showitem' with fieldName = 'sys_language_uid' has been migrated, from TCA table "tx_arbeiten_domain_model_diplomarbeiten['types']['1']['showitem']"to "tx_arbeiten_domain_model_diplomarbeiten['types']['1']['columnsOverrides']['sys_language_uid']['defaultExtras']".

Go to:

**TYPO3 Backend -> Configuration -> $GLOBALS[‘TCA’](Table configuration array) -> tx_arbeiten_domain_model_diplomarbeiten -> types -> 1 -> showitems**

Copy the updated values from there, in this case:

> showitem = **sys_language_uid,l10n_parent,l10n_diffsource,hidden,--palette--;;1,authorfirstname,author,author2firstname,author2,author3firstname,author3,title,schoolclass,link,--palette--;Datei 1;downloadgroup,--palette--;Datei 2;download2group,--palette--;Datei 3;download3group,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.access,starttime,endtime**

and paste them into your extension's TCA file (again at `['types']['1']['showitem']`)

Comment: better solution than accepted, after use first i had problem with --palette--